# Конвертирование с помощью интерфейса в C#

Tags: c#, массивы, преобразование

Можно ли преобразовать массив объектов одного типа (класс) в массив объектов другого типа (структура) если они использую общий интерфейс ? Вот как у меня получается:

```
public interface ISomeInterface {}
public class SomeObject1 : ISomeInterface {}
public struct SomeObject2 : ISomeInterface {}

public static Main(string args)
{
   ISomeInterface obj1 = new SomeObject1 (); // Хорошо все получилось
   ISomeInterface obj2 = new SomeObject2 (); // Хорошо все получилось
   obj1 = obj2; // все еще хорошо
   obj2 = obj1; // или так - все еще хорошо
   
   ISomeInterface[] objects1 = new ISomeInterface[10];
   SomeObject2[]    objects2 = new SomeObject2[10];
   objects1 = objects2 // вот тут проблемы
}
```

Я пробовал переопределить явный/неявный (explicit/implicit) оператор, но он походит только для единичных случаев (один к одному).. Но массив к массиву не получается явно/неявно (explicit/implicit) привести. Помогите пожалуйста, это в моем коде столько бы грязи убрало...

Comment: А это что за язык-то? C#? Вообще так нельзя, насколько я помню, в java по-крайней мере.

Comment: @Zhenyria да это C# , было бы очень круто, если бы не приходилось конвертировать.. Ну или иметь способ который не делает такую ситуацию с конвертированием.

Comment: Почему проблемы? Ваш код работает.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Извините, что ввел в заблуждение, это работает для классов, а в моем случае Один тип - это класс производный от некого интерфейса, а другой тип - это структура производная от того же интерфейса. 

Сейчас подправлю вопрос.

Comment: `objects1 = objects2.Select(x => (ISomeInterface)x).ToArray();` - думаю, только так

Comment: Используйте сторонные библиотеки

Comment: @ Alexander Petrov да, именно так и есть у меня. Спасибо! Я просто ищу лучшее решение.